# What does "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check" mean?

Tags: ajax, cors

I have receive the following response when trying to access an API via an ajax request in Chrome:

"Failed to load http://localhost:1880/api_resource: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin http://localhost:3000 is therefore not allowed access."

As you can see from the message, both client and API are running locally.

I understand that this situation relates to a CORS cross origin request.  I see that there are similar questions about this on stack overflow, but from those answers I do not understand what the message is telling me and where it comes from.

Specifically I understand that the *response* header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" must be set (typically to '*') to allow access to the API from a different domain to the one on which the API is being served.  But the message seems to relate to the request and not the response, and as far as I am aware, no request ever reaches the API.

What is a preflight request and how is it failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I now understand it, modern browsers will issue a 'preflight' request before the actual cross origin request.  This preflight request uses the 'OPTIONS' HTTP verb along with the CORS headers `Access-Control-Request-Method` and `Access-Control-Request-Headers` to which it expects to see a response with valid `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the header that indicates that the server understands the CORS protocol and will allow the actual (GET/POST/PUT) request.

The message "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check" means that the browser did not see a valid "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in the Options response.

In my case this was because the server (implementing a REST API) was set up to respond correctly to PUT and POST requests but not setup to respond to OPTIONS requests with the CORS headers.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was for my website address, i'm calling all apis from the same server but i got this error.

my website address is sateh.ir
so im my ajax request i set the url: http://sateh.ir/api/...

after getting this error and working on it for some hours, i got that i had to set ajax url to: http://www.sateh.ir/api/...

i dont know why my website cant understand that i'm calling api from the same server if i dont put 'www', but that was my problem at all.